# How can merge branch into master in MuleSoft (Anypoint design center)

Tags: mulesoft, anypoint-studio, raml, anypoint-platform

We have created multiple RAML file in Design Center (Anypoint Platform - Mulesoft). We are working in team so multiple users can edit that RAML file by creating separate branch. Now I want to merge those branches into master branch. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the documentation says that [branches can not be merged back](https://docs.mulesoft.com/design-center/design-branching#about-this-task):

> A new branch is a fork of your project and cannot be merged back into the master branch.

An alternative is to download the API from both branches, uncompress into separate directories, then merge them manually using tools for your operating system, like windiff, command line diff or some other equivalent tools.