# How to merge a branch into the master in API raml mulesoft API Design center?

Tags: api-design, branching-and-merging, mulesoft, raml, anypoint-platform

I made a branch to create API RAML file in Design center MULESOFT cloud. Is it possible to merge branch in a master ?

In attached the image of the action to do.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can merge branch into master in MuleSoft (Anypoint design center)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287066/how-can-merge-branch-into-master-in-mulesoft-anypoint-design-center)

Comment: Thanks, as documentation told : a new branch is a fork of your project and cannot be merged back into the master branch